# clear cookie file in Libcurl

Tags: c, http, libcurl

I'm trying to clear all stored cookies in Libcurl (version 7.21.6) but
nothing really seems to work.

What command should I use?
I'm using the C-binding version.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem. How are you trying to delete? Do you know where is your cookie is stored?

Comment: My cookies are stored in a file using the command res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,cookieFileLocation.c_str()); I tried to delete them by invoking curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, "ALL" );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "clear" a cookie file (on disk) with libcurl. Just remove it from the file system with a normal system function such as unlink() or zero it with truncate().

You can clear all cookies libcurl knows about in memory with CURLOPT_COOKIELIST "ALL".